# How can I pass a "C++ completion handler" to NSURLSessionDataTask to process the data it returned?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c++, completionhandler

Our application is written mostly in C++, the core of which is static library shared by multiple platforms (Win, Mac, Android, iOS).

We're adding iOS support, and have a series of functions that use libcurl that perform all of the HTTP get/post communication with our servers.

But for iOS, we're now implementing those calls using NSURLSession.

My question is pretty simple, how does the code look like to provide a C++ completionHandler to NSURLSessionDataTask?

Perhaps I'm thinking about this the wrong way, but that is the clearest I can think to make the question.

Using example code out in the world, I tried the following, to no avail. The Objective-C++ code inside the completion handler never gets called. It returns to the C++ code and never returns.

This is the objective-C++ function:

```
std::string get(std::string urlStr)
{
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:urlStr.c_str()]];

    __block std::string returnVal;

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithURL:url
                                                         completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(error == nil)
        {
            NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);

            returnVal = std::string([text UTF8String]);
        }

    }];

    [dataTask resume];

    return returnVal;
}
```

And this is how I invoke that code in the C++:

```
    response = get(url);
    fprintf(stderr, "Data in C++: %s", response.c_str());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're wanting `get(std::string)` to "call you back" when it's done fetching.  If you're willing to change the interface of `get` then one way would be to pass a `std::function` as a parameter ...

```
void get(std::string urlStr, std::function<void(std::string)> callback)
{
  ...
  NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = 
    [defaultSession 
      dataTaskWithURL:url 
      completionHandler:
        ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
          if(error == nil)
          {
             NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);

             // invoke the callback here...
             callback(std::string([text UTF8String]));
          }
        }];
  ...
}
```

This would be used like so ...

```
void callbackFunc(std::string data)
{
  ...
}

get("...", callbackFunc);
```

Another way of structuring this would be to use c++'s new `std::promise` and `std::future` types ...

```
std::future<std::string> get(std::string urlStr)
{
  ...
  __block std::promise<std::string> p{};

  NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = 
    [defaultSession 
      dataTaskWithURL:url 
      completionHandler:
        ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
          if(error == nil)
          {
             NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);

             // Set the result value here...
             p.set_value(std::string([text UTF8String]));
          }
        }
    ];
  ...
  return p.get_future();
}
```

This can then be used like so ...

```
auto result = get("...");

// other processing here ...
...

auto result_value = result.get();
```

**Note:** I should point out that I've assumed the use of c++11/14. If you're using c++03 then you could still use the 1st method by using `boost::function` or a bare function pointer - `void(*)(std::string)`. I'm also not too familiar with OS X's blocks feature so be wary of my syntax.

Comment: Yes, excellent! You got at what I was trying to ask... I wasn't sure if std::function would be the proper type as in cases where I'm passing around a C++ callback normally. Thank you so much for your detailed response!

Comment: @A.G. Glad I could help. I guess one of the advantages of having a `std::function` parameter is that you could pass the result of a `std::bind` to `get`, meaning that there are pretty much limitless targets to `callback`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood how `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:` works; it's asynchronous (as are most network operations), meaning that the task will operate on a separate thread and not block the calling thread.

This means that you will return from `get(..)` before your `NSURLSessionDataTask` is complete.

If you want to make a synchronous network call, you'll have to block or busy-wait until `returnVal` is populated. I've modified your obj-c code to use `dispatch_semaphore_t`s following the lead of [this class](https://github.com/floschliep/NSURLSession-SynchronousTask/blob/master/NSURLSession%2BSynchronousTask.m).

```
std::string get(std::string urlStr)
{
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:urlStr.c_str()]];

    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    __block std::string returnVal;

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithURL:url
                                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(error == nil)
        {
            NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);

            returnVal = std::string([text UTF8String]);
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

    }];

    [dataTask resume];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    return returnVal;
}
```

---

**Edit**: According to your comment, you are looking for a function pointer. *Note that the code below is completely untested, but should at least point you in the right direction.*

```
void get(std::string urlStr, void (*callback)(std::string)) {
  [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url
                               completionHandler:^(NSData *, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    std::string returnVal;
    if(error == nil)
    {
        NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);

        returnVal = std::string([text UTF8String]);
    }
    callback(returnVal);
  }] resume];
}

void my_callback(std::string) {
  // do stuff with the response.
}

get(my_url, my_callback);
```

Comment: Right, no, I get that. I should have been more clear... what would a completionHnadler in C++ look like that I could pass down to have it called when the dataTask has returned?